# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with postman API only

Tags: mysql, laravel, api, postman, sequelpro

I'm using postman to try and make an API post request:

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/register?name=corbin&email=corbin@example.com&password=password

There must be a database connecting because I can migrate my db just fine. Using `php artisan tinker` I can also add a new user just fine:

```
>>> $user = new User();
=> App\User {#3060}
>>> $user->name = "kyle";
=> "kyle"
>>> $user->email = "kyle@example.com"
=> "kyle@example.com"
>>> $user->email = "kyle@example.com";
=> "kyle@example.com"
>>> $user->password = bcrypt('password');
=> "$2y$10$VQ8i0wlUKOfMzz6s/AXNBekcAdDAah9EvCvLeOASu3t06x.eVMCFq"
>>> $user->save();
=> true
>>> User::all();
=> Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#3080
     all: [
       App\User {#3081
         id: 1,
         name: "kyle",
         email: "kyle@example.com",
         email_verified_at: null,
         created_at: "2020-04-29 06:15:03",
         updated_at: "2020-04-29 06:15:03",
       },
     ],
   }
```

However when I try and create a record in postman I get this:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: insert into `users` (`name`, `email`, `password`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (kyle, kyle@example.com, $2y$10$QfVSBr67zOJldKrxqjVVsO9pZ5QV9qOkvoCH./FPRZfSRVo1A4GqC, 2020-04-28 08:53:51, 2020-04-28 08:53:51)) in file /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/laravel-vue-spa/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php on line 671

Here's my AuthController:

```
public function register(Request $request)
    {


        /*$request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed'
        ]);*/

        $user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);

        $user->save();

        /*if($user->save()){
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'User was successfully created.',
                'status_code' => 201
            ], 201);
        } else {
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'An error occured. Please try again.',
                'status_code' => 500
            ], 500);
        } */
    }
```

**.env**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel_spa
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=password
```

I also tried switching `DB_HOST=localhost`. In Sequel Pro my privileges are set to super. I've also tried doing a `GET` request for `User::all();` same ordeal.

## Edit 1

**config/database.php**

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

I have also ran `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: when you change something in the env file you have to run this command php artisan config:cache

Comment: `php artisan optimize:clear` is best for clearing all cache

Comment: what triggers me is the `(using password: NO)` can you share your `config/database.php` ?

Comment: Ah @Sergio got it!

Comment: my advice is don't use artisan serve for local development try to use some web server like apache2 or something else. At least you won't run to problem like this for development.

Comment: If the question is solved please wite the answer and accept it so it can help others as well 